# How to Open Port 1433 on Raspberry Pi?

Tags: raspberry-pi, port, telnet, netsh, ufw

I have tried to connect to MSSQl Database from raspberry pi. However, I have a few errors coming. I try to telnet the server ip address like that.

```
telnet 192.168.10.70 1433
Trying 192.168.10.70
Connected to 192.168.10.70
Escape character is '^]'
```

However,to check if a server has port 1433 listening, I run `netstat -ano -p |find “1433”` in command prompt but the error is `No such file or directory`.

So I think running the netstat command on Pi returns no result because there is no port 1433 open on Pi, not server. So anyone knows how to open the port in Pi?

I have used ufw but after it is enabled, I cannot ssh. Do we really need ufw? That's the part I am confusing.

Comment: The `find` command on Linux is not for searching for text; it is for looking for files by name (and other criteria). You are looking for the `grep` command: `netstat -ano -p | grep 1433`.

Comment: Questions about using your operating system (opening a port on RaspberryPi) are not programming-related, and therefore are off-topic here. You're looking for [raspberrypi.se] or [unix.se] instead. You can find more information about this site in the [help].